# Android transparent image in popup window is not transparent

Tags: android, image, transparent, popupwindow

I am trying to display a tranparent image as popup window. For that I have customized the popupwindow as per my need and inflating a relative layout in that popupwindow initview().

In that relative layout I have added a transparent image, but when I run the app, its a oval image inside the rectangular box, so instead of transparancy i could see gray color around that oval image.

I dont have any option than popupwindow, because I should use the controls in the background screen.

I have tried setting the transparent style for this relative layout, eventhough its not working.

Can any one tell me how to do this

or

is there a bug in android popupwindow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found a solution for this - While customizing the popup window we have to set the background as null. setBackgroundDrawable(null); Then it worked.

Comment: setting the background to null causes the onTouch listeners to stop working

Comment: ByteMe is correct. it will cause the onTouch listeners to stop working if you are using them

Comment: try adding this pw.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources()));

Comment: This solutions isnt working as this will create a white or tranparent patch when i click over action item

Comment: This works for me and `onTouchListener()` is working fine:
`setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Answer (score 2):

There is the right solution. The issue is that the background of the
popupWindow is define in the theme style of the activity.

Solution:

1. define your custom theme for the application or the
   activity displaying the PopupWindow.

   - you can choose a different parent theme.
   - customize the entry "android:popupWindowStyle"

     ```
     <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
         <item name="android:popupWindowStyle">@style/PopupWindow</item> 
     </style>
     ```
2. define the popupWindowStyle.     entry "android:popupBacground"
   define the background for all popupWindow display with this specific
   theme.

   ```
   <style name="PopupWindow" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/transparent</item> 
   </style>
   ```
3. add the CustomTheme theme to the activity or application

   ```
   <application
           ...
           android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
   ```

The popupWindow will display with a transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

Use android themes in your pop up.. If it is an activity declare it in Manifest.

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

**EDIT**
Set theme for dialog like this

> mDialogTax = new Dialog(mContext,
>                   android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

Answer (score 0):

Laurent,

**We need to set the transparency to our view after we inflate it:**

```
inflatedView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

The component to which we anchor the PopupWindow is not required to be transparent even though it might be a layout.

**Setting the background of the PopupWindow is not required:**

<strike>`this.setBackgroundDrawable(null);`</strike>

**Setting the alpha value is not required:**

<strike>`this.getBackground().setAlpha(<value>);`</strike>

**Setting the image background if it is a PNG is not required:**

<strike>`imageView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);`</strike>

**Setting the image background in it's xml definition is not required:**

```
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/myimage"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />
```

Thanks...

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply, At first I tried setting the background of that image as transparent only, but it didnt work. Let me explain u the scenario. I have to show one image on the screen, both the image and screen should be click able, so I have used popup window. I have tried with transparent background on the layout and styles, both didnt work. Then in the initView of my popup window I set the background as null then it worked.

Comment: Kindly Ravindranath Akila please show the code where u set drawable to null (which class), i m having the same problem

Comment: @RaoAsadUllah, so sorry I am unable to do this as it is a long time back since I did this project and on experimental basis. Chances are I deleted it. However, if you really are desperate, let me know, I will try to pull it off one of my old hard disks :-)